# C++ Binary Tree Path finding

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have a question regarding finding sum of a path of a binary int tree. This is for college so the requirements are as follows:
Take your code from Lab Sheet 3B (Binary Tree) for a binary tree of integers, and code a
method called hasPathSum() which given a binary tree and a sum, return true if the tree
has a root-to-leaf path such that adding up all the values along the path equals the given
sum. Return false if no such path can be found. The function prototype is

```
int hasPathSum(struct node* node, int sum)
```

Note: a "root-to-leaf path" is a sequence of nodes in a tree starting with the root node
and proceeding downward to a leaf (a node with no children). An empty tree contains
no root-to-leaf paths. So for example, the following tree has exactly four root-to-leaf
paths:

```
5
/ \
4 8
/ / \
11 13 4
/ \ \
7 2 1
Root-to-leaf paths:
path 1: 5 4 11 7
path 2: 5 4 11 2
path 3: 5 8 13
path 4: 5 8 4 1
```

For this problem, we will be concerned with the sum of the values of such a path -- for
example, the sum of the values on the 5-4-11-7 path is 5 + 4 + 11 + 7 = 27.

I am having trouble with this. I have a binary tree, but the function hasPathSum() requirs to pass a node, not a tree. I canot figure out how to do this. I also don't know how to find the sum of a path from root to leaf (the hasPathSum body as well). This needs to be done recursively.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my node class:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma once
struct TreeNode
{
public:
    friend class BinaryTree;
    TreeNode(int theData) : data(theData) {}
    bool isLeaf();
private:
    int data;
    TreeNode *leftlink;
    TreeNode *rightLink;
};
```

Here is the BinaryTree header file:

```
#include "TreeNode.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma once
class BinaryTree
{
public:
    BinaryTree();
    void add(int toadd);
    int height();
    void inorderShow() const;
    int hasPathSum(TreeNode * tree, int sum);
private:
    void add(TreeNode *toAdd, TreeNode *& addHere);
    int height(TreeNode *& root);
    TreeNode *root;
    void inorderShow(TreeNode *subTree) const;
};
```

And my BinaryTree cpp file:

```
#include "BinaryTree.h"

BinaryTree::BinaryTree()
{
}

void BinaryTree::add(int toAdd)
{
    TreeNode *node = new TreeNode(toAdd);
    add(node, root);
}

int BinaryTree::height()
{
    return height(root);
}

void BinaryTree::add(TreeNode * toAdd, TreeNode *& addHere)
{
    if (addHere == NULL)
        addHere = toAdd;
    else if (toAdd->data < addHere->data)
        add(toAdd, addHere->leftlink);
    else //toAdd->data >= addHere->data
        add(toAdd, addHere->rightLink);
}

int BinaryTree::height(TreeNode *& n)
{
    if (n == NULL)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1 + max(height(n->leftlink), height(n->rightLink));
}

void BinaryTree::inorderShow(TreeNode * subTree) const
{
    if (subTree != NULL)
    {
        inorderShow(subTree->leftlink);
        cout << subTree->data << " ";
        inorderShow(subTree->rightLink);
    }
}

void BinaryTree::inorderShow() const
{
    inorderShow(root);
}

int BinaryTree::hasPathSum(TreeNode * tree, int sum)
{

}
```

In the main.cpp, I have a tree as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "BinaryTree.h"
#include "TreeNode.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BinaryTree tree;
    tree.add(5);
    tree.add(6);
    tree.add(3);
    tree.add(4);
    tree.add(9);
    tree.add(11);
    cout << "Height of the tree is: ";
    cout << tree.height() << " ";

    cout << "\nIn Order Show:" << endl;
    tree.inorderShow();

    cout << "Root to leaft path: " << endl;

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Is someone could explain how can I accomplish this task and meet the requirements (aka not change the function hasPathSum() parameters) I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Asking here to do your homework for you is considered off-topic as _too broad_. At least show your own attempt and explain where you're stuck specifically.

Comment: I am stuck in the main function at the point where I have to enter the hasPathSum() function. The function requires me to enter a node as a first parameter, but I don't know how to pass a node from my existing tree - the root value is private and I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: You probably have to implement a function to access an arbitrary node from your BST (hint: S is for search()).

Comment: The requirement of (a) returning an int for "hasPathSum()" and the convention within the C++ community (b) that only the integer 0 indicates 'false',  would motivate me to code your function to return int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me the requirement is wrong (or maybe confused)

> and code a method called hasPathSum() which given a binary tree and a
>   sum

So given that this is a method of the binary tree class the tree is passed implicitly so the only explicit parameter is the sum. So the method should be declared as

```
class BinaryTree
{
    ...
    bool hasPathSum(int sum);
    ...
};
```

However the given signature is

> int hasPathSum(struct node* node, int sum)

which has the wrong return type (`int` not `bool`) and an unexplained `node` parameter.

Here's how I would organise the solution, since it involves two methods, it maybe explains the confusion.

```
class BinaryTree
{
    ...
public:
    bool hasPathSum(int sum) { return hasPathSumHelper(root, sum); }
    ...
private:
    static bool hasPathSumHelper(TreeNode* node, int sum);
};
```

The public `hasPathSum` method has the signature implied by the problem description (the only signature that makes sense). It simply calls a private method `hasPathSumHelper` passing the root node and the sum, this gets round the problem of how you pass the private root node.

The `hasPathSumHelper` method is the recursive routine where the real work is done (left for you to implement). The public `hasPathSum` just kicks off the calculation by calling this method.

As you think about how to implement the `hasPathSumHelper` you might find it useful to add additional parameters (a `sum_so_far` parameter which, as you descend the tree, is the sum of all the nodes above you makes sense to me). That's OK because it's a private method, you can add what you like.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I will just assume that the requirement is wrong as i was wondering why is at asking to return true or false but actually has an int as a return type.

Comment: The requirement of (a) returning an int for "hasPathSum()" and the convention within the C++ community (b) that only the integer 0 indicates 'false',  would motivate me to code your function to return int.